# Bought wrong laptop keyboard, need a way to map keys

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I bought the wrong laptop keyboard(stupid amazon tricked me!). They do not have the correct one as a replacement any more.

The new one has 4 more pins on the connector BUT they are all connected together. I cut them out and was able to connect the keyboard to the lap top.

The keys work except they are all wrong. I guess because the matrix is different. I need a way to map the scancodes in windows so I can use this keyboard. (It would be nice to have a very low level way to do this so it won't screw up programs that use the low level scan codes).

Any ideas? At this point I just need to use the keyboard to work well enough to do basic tasks.

Comment: you don't think it would be easier to get the right keyboard, even if it means getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: @BonGart You are acting like you are saying something important... Do you really think that you're the only one smart enough to come up with that kind of conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I downloaded autohotkey - (http://www.autohotkey.com) Very easy to remap SHIFT+3 for £ etc ...

Comment: Does it work with programs that read by scan codes? (like some games)

Comment: I have no idea. Autohotkey does quite a few things. Try it.